# having 3 tables "student","dept","prev_edu"...tbl student is parent and its 'id' is FK in others

Tags: php, mysql

having 3 tables "student","dept","prev_edu"...table student is parent and its 'id' is FK in others...i am inserting records but in other two tables(dept,prev_edu) the sql does not work....just inserts data into table 'student' .....here's specific code..(usnig php my admin).... what should b there????

```
if($query=="insert_student"){ 
      $sql ="Insert Into student Values(' ','".$_POST["txtName"]."','".$_POST["txtfatherName"]."','".$_POST["txtdob"]."','".$_POST["txtgender"]."','".$_POST["txtcnic"]."','".$_POST ["txtMstatus"]."','".$_POST["txtemail"]."','".$_POST["txtaddress"]."','".$_POST["txtoccupation"]."','".$_POST["txtcommaddress"]."','".$_POST["txtnationality"]."','".$_POST["txtrstatus"]."','".$_POST["txtphoneno"]."','".$_POST["txtmob"]."')";

        if(mysql_query($sql,$link) ){ 
  $sqlrs =  "Insert Into dept Values('?','".$_POST["txtcampus"]."','".$_POST["txtprogram"]."','".$_POST["txtDegree"]."','' )";
    if( mysql_query($sqlrs,$link) ){


    $sqlrss = "INSERT INTO prev_edu VALUES ('?','".$_POST["txtClass1"]."','".$_POST["txtYear1"]."','".$_POST["txtAnnual1"]."','".$_POST["txtRollno1"]."','".$_POST["txtMarks1"]."','".$_POST ["txtResult1"]."','".$_POST["txtGroup1"]."','".$_POST["txtBoard1"]."','' )";

            if( mysql_query($sqlrss,$link) ){  
        header("Location: Main.html");
    }else {

        header("Location: Error.php?msg=Insertion Failed");
```

Comment: Use `echo mysql_error();` after the insert query which is not working to debug errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($query=="insert_student"){ 
      $sql ="INSERT INTO student VALUES('',
                                        '".$_POST["txtName"]."',
                                        '".$_POST["txtfatherName"]."',
                                        '".$_POST["txtdob"]."',
                                        '".$_POST["txtgender"]."',
                                        '".$_POST["txtcnic"]."',
                                        '".$_POST ["txtMstatus"]."',
                                        '".$_POST["txtemail"]."',
                                        '".$_POST["txtaddress"]."',
                                        '".$_POST["txtoccupation"]."',
                                        '".$_POST["txtcommaddress"]."',
                                        '".$_POST["txtnationality"]."',
                                        '".$_POST["txtrstatus"]."',
                                        '".$_POST["txtphoneno"]."',
                                        '".$_POST["txtmob"]."'
                                       )";
      @mysql_query($sql, $link);
      if(mysql_affected_rows($link) == 1){ 
          //get the last insert ID (SID)
          $sid = mysql_insert_id($link);
          $sqlrs =  "INSERT INTO dept VALUES('',
                                             '".$_POST["txtcampus"]."',
                                             '".$_POST["txtprogram"]."',
                                             '".$_POST["txtDegree"]."',
                                             '".$sid."' 
                                            )";
          @mysql_query($sqlrs, $link);
          if(mysql_affected_rows($link) == 1){
             $sqlrss = "INSERT INTO prev_edu VALUES ('',
                                                     '".$_POST["txtClass1"]."',
                                                     '".$_POST["txtYear1"]."',
                                                     '".$_POST["txtAnnual1"]."',
                                                     '".$_POST["txtRollno1"]."',
                                                     '".$_POST["txtMarks1"]."',
                                                     '".$_POST ["txtResult1"]."',
                                                     '".$_POST["txtGroup1"]."',
                                                     '".$_POST["txtBoard1"]."',
                                                     '".$sid."'
                                                     )";
             @mysql_query($sqlrss, $link);

            if(mysql_affected_rows($link) == 1){  
              @header("Location:Main.html");
              exit;
            }
          }
     }
     header("Location:Error.php?msg=Insertion Failed");
}
```

Comment: try to post here you tables structure

Comment: tble structure is 
student(sid(PK),name, fathername, value, value)
dept(did(pk),campus,degree,prog,sid(FK))
prev_edu(pid(pk),value,value,sid(FK))

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of mysql since mysql_* function are deprecated. Also you must `validate` the user input properly and try to use `prepared statements` as they help you avoid SQL injection attacks. Next i assume by putting `?` in your query, that field is your primary key with auto-increment.

You can try the following :

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("hostname", "username", "password", "database_name");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

// here ***....*** indicates the rest of the fields

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO student VALUES('',?,?....)"; 
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss...", $_POST["txtName"],$_POST["txtdob"],....);
```

Also i am guessing that you are trying to save the user_id the subsequent queries.

I hope this helps you. See more info on prepared statements [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: thnx for suggestion....But i dont care of sql injection at this level....Only problm is thr..that other two quries($sql & $sqlrs ) are not working ....i knw that there is FK constraints prob some whre

Comment: I am guessing that you are trying to save the student id in subsequent queries, right?

Comment: You can get that with `mysql_insert_id()` in mysql and `$mysqli->insert_id` with mysqli